# Redis-py: run_in_thread eventhandler stops getting called after few hours

Tags: python, redis, publish-subscribe, redis-py

I'm trying to implement a basic pubsub using redis-py client.
The idea is, the publisher is actually a callback that gets called periodically and will publish some information on *channel1* in the callback function.

The subscriber will listen on that channel for this message and do some processing accordingly.

The subscriber is actually a basic bare-bones webserver that is deployed on k8s and it simply should show up the messages that it receives via the *event_handler* function.

*subscriber.py*

```
class Sub(object):
   def __init___(self):
      redis = Redis(host=...,
              port=...,
              password=...,
              db=0)
      ps = redis.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
      ps.subscribe(**{'channel1': Sub.event_handler})
      ps.run_in_thread(sleep_time=0.01, daemon=True)

   @staticmethod
   def event_handler(msg):
      print("Hello from event handler")
      if msg and msg.get('type') == 'message': # interested only in messages, not subscribe/unsubscribe/pmessages
         # process the message
```

*publisher.py*

```
redis = Redis(host=...,
              port=...,
              password=...,
              db=0)

def call_back(msg):
    global redis
    redis.publish('channel1', msg)
```

At the beginning, the messages are published and the subscriber event handler prints and process it correctly.

The problem is, after few hours, the subscriber stops showing up those messages. I've checked publisher logs and the messages definitely get sent out, but I'm not able to figure out why the *event_handler* is not getting called after few hours.

The *print* statement in it stops getting printed which is why I say the handler is not getting fired after few hours.

Initially I suspected the thread must have died, but on exec into the system I see it listed under the list of threads.
I've read through a lot of blogs, documentations but haven't found much help.

All I can deduce is the event handler stops getting called after sometime.
Can anyone help understand what's going on and the best way to reliably consume pubsub messages in a non blocking way?

Really appreciate any insights you guys have! :(

Answer (score 0):

could you post the whole `puplisher.py`, please? It could be the case that `call_back(msg)` isn't called anymore.

To check whether a client is still subscribed, you can use the command `PUBSUB CHANNELS` in `reds-cli`.

Regards, Martin

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked the publisher call_back does get called in the logs. I checked the redis host and ran the command PUBSUB NUMSUB channel1 and it says 0 subscribers. However, on subscriber.py restart, it shows 1 subscriber as it should, so I believe for some reason the connection is not being maintained, the entire thing is deployed on k8s if it helps

Comment: Check connection timeouts, in Redis and in infrastructure.